# get data from return value of mandrillapp array

Tags: php, mandrill

Mandrill app return this : `[{"email":"steven@gmail.com","status":"sent","_id":"234we4fvba4a3e8517d7a9","reject_reason":null}]`

I need to get only the value of "status". Something like this: `echo $result['status'];` How can I do it in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `json_decode()` to get the status.. like this :

```
<?php

$str = '[{"email":"steven@gmail.com","status":"sent","_id":"234we4fvba4a3e8517d7a9","reject_reason":null}]';
$json = json_decode($str, true);
echo $json[0]['status'];

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like

```
$json = '[{"email":"steven@gmail.com","status":"sent","_id":"234we4fvba4a3e8517d7a9","reject_reason":null}]';
$json_array = json_decode($json);
print "<pre>";print_r($json_array[0]->status);
```