# Curl Response to php object

Tags: php, curl

I making this curl request:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/order?startDate=2016-01-01&endDate=2016-05-03&status=approved");
    curl_setopt(
            $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array(
                    'Snapdeal-Affiliate-Id:'.$affiliateId,
                    'Snapdeal-Token-Id:'.$token,
                    'Accept:application/json'
            )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // work with $response here:

     $jsonData = json_decode($response);
     Mage::log( $jsonData["productDetails"][0]["product"]);
```

The response is this:

```
{"productDetails":[{"product":"Philips QT4000 Trimmer Black","category":"Appliances","orderCode":"12569696012","quantity":1,"price":936.0,"sale":936.0,"commissionRate":1.0,"commissionEarned":9.36,"dateTime":"03/29/2016 22:49:06","affiliateSubId1":"","affiliateSubId2":"null","userType":"EXISTING","deviceType":"web"}],"nextURL":null}
```

The log statement prints nothing. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get data from return value of mandrillapp array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018951/get-data-from-return-value-of-mandrillapp-array)

Comment: [VISIT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37019007/4018240) this, use `json_decode($response,true)` it will return a associative array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` in your curl and pass `true` with `json_decode()`....

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "affiliate-feeds.snapdeal.com/feed/api/order?startDate=2016-01-01&endDate=2016-05-03&status=approved");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt(
            $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array(
                    'Snapdeal-Affiliate-Id:'.$affiliateId,
                    'Snapdeal-Token-Id:'.$token,
                    'Accept:application/json'
            )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // work with $response here:
    $jsonData = json_decode($response,true);
     Mage::log($jsonData['productDetails'][0]['product']);
```

This will output :

```
Philips QT4000 Trimmer Black
```

Comment: I made that change: Here it is:    $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
   
  // work with $response here:
   
   $jsonData = json_decode($response,true);
   Mage::log( $jsonData["productDetails"][0]["product"],null,"mylogfile1.log",true);  still prints nothing

Comment: use `$array['productDetails'][0]['product']` instead of `$jsonData->productDetails[0]->product` in log..

Comment: `json_decode($json,true)` return associative array, associative array is printed with key to value like `$array['key']` not `$array->key`

Comment: simply use `echo $jsonData['productDetails'][0]['product']` and see what is printed...

Comment: It prints the complete json response. Shall we move to chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110985/discussion-between-manjeet-barnala-and-mayank).

Answer (score 2):

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) decodes to an object by default. Do `$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);` if you want an associative array.

Comment: I made that change, its still giving me nothing. Can you write the full statement to be  used inside log

Comment: @mayank You don't need to change the statement inside the call to `log`. I've just tested this with the JSON you provided and it works fine. Are you sure you are looking in the correct file for the log output?

Comment: You are using the json directly, maybe thats the issue. Maybe, getting the curl response and then using json_decode on it seems to be the trouble. Maybe I have to convert the curl response to something

Answer (score 1):

```
Mage::log( $jsonData->productDetails[0]->product);
```

Or use associate array as mentioned.

Comment: still doesn't prints anything

Comment: @mayank When you say it "doesn't prints anything" what do you mean? It is a log method so it is most likely logging to a file instead of producing output. Use `echo` if you want output.

Comment: sorry for wrong wording, it logs nothing,( an empty value)

Comment: Use
var_dump($jsonData->productDetails[0]->product)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you make a curl call and get the content from that website

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('curl_version')) {
    exit("Enable cURL in PHP");
}

$url = "https://www.google.com/";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Accept: */*",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Connection: keep-alive",
        "Host: " . url($url),
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36",
        "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
    ),
));

function url($url)
{
    $result = parse_url($url);
    return $result['host'];
}
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo "<textarea>" . $response . "</textarea>";

}
```